# Power BI - Extract Transpose Alternate Rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table which contains 1 column. It looks like this:

```
Column1
https://www.google.com
2019-03-12T11:15:30-05:00
https://www.twitter.com
2019-03-06T11:10:05-06:00
```

What I am trying to do is take the second row and transpose it to a new column.

```
Column1                  Column2
https://www.google.com   2019-03-12T11:15:30-05:00
https://www.twitter.com  2019-03-06T11:10:05-06:00
```

What is the best way to do this? I don't care if it's in the query editor or in DAX, however in DAX the columns aren't sorted the same way they came in (and in this case, each date is associated with the link above it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query editor, write a custom column that looks at the first few characters to distinguish between URL and date. Then pivot on that column.

**Edit:** It looks like you'll need to index each pair to pivot properly, so add an index from 0 and integer divide by 2 to get `0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3,...`, which groups each pair together nicely.

---

```
let
    Source = <Your Source>,
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each if Text.Start([Column1],1) = "h" then "URL" else "Date"),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Added Custom", "Index", 0, 1),
    #"Integer-Divided Column" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"Index", each Number.IntegerDivide(_, 2), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Integer-Divided Column", List.Distinct(#"Integer-Divided Column"[Custom]), "Custom", "Column1")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: Yeaaaaa... that's kind of what I was thinking, but when I set the Aggregate Value Function to "Don't Aggregate" it gives me an error: "Expression.Error: There were too many elements in the enumeration to complete the operation."   I'm only working with 12k rows so all I can think of is that one of my previous steps is the cause.. I removed several columns prior to the pivot - I'm pretty sure that wouldn't affect it but that's all I can come up with..

Comment: Yeah, it needs to know how to distinguish between multiple rows with the same value. Try adding an index. (See my edit.)